# How to generate alert if first 5 digits in a string are zero using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox which accept mobile no or phone no. I have written validation that this textbox should accept only numbers. But i have a one more requirement i.e if user input first five digits as 0 in a text box then it should through an error or display some message.
I am trying to do this using java script but didnt find good solution on google.
Can you please help me... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code with us??

Comment: "regular expressions"

Comment: if(string.substr(0,5) == "00000") throwError()

Comment: I am using "(/^(0){5}[0-9]$/)" this regular expression to validate but it throws me an error even if user input first 3 digits as 0.

Comment: We can't tell what could be a problem with your code if you don't show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var mob = "0000023";

mob = mob.substring(0, 5);

if(mob.trim() == '00000')
  alert('error');
else
  alert('ok');
```

Comment: You should trim the input *before* substringing it, otherwise it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Juhana, CodingAnt... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This code below should match any input that either begins with five 0 or contains a non-numeric character:

```
^0{5}|\D
```

Answer (score -1):

Given you are already using regular expressions, how about the reg exps used in the jquery-validate library? I'm not sure what country you're in, but it sounds like it might be the UK, in which case their method for 'phonesUK' might be what you need. Here it is by itself:

```
//Matches UK landline + mobile, accepting only 01-3 for landline or 07 for mobile to exclude many premium numbers
jQuery.validator.addMethod('phonesUK', function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\(|\)|\s+|-/g,'');
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(?:(?:(?:00\s?|\+)44\s?|0)(?:1\d{8,9}|[23]\d{9}|7(?:[45789]\d{8}|624\d{6})))$/);
}, 'Please specify a valid uk phone number');
```

So you could extract it and use it like this:

```
var phone_number = "01223 123456";
phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\(|\)|\s+|-/g,'');
var valid = phone_number.length > 9 &&
    phone_number.match(/^(?:(?:(?:00\s?|\+)44\s?|0)(?:1\d{8,9}|[23]\d{9}|7(?:[45789]\d{8}|624\d{6})))$/);
```